# Java let superclass return type of extended class

Tags: java, inheritance

My current situation:
I have a superclass Matrix:

```
public class Matrix {
  private final float[] values;
  private final int numberOfRows;
  private final int numberOfColumns;

  public Matrix(int rows, int columns, float... values) {
    this.values = new float[numberOfRows * numberOfColumns];
    this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
    this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, this.values, 0, values.length);
  }

  public Matrix scale(int scaleFactor) {
    //Some code that returns a scaled version of the matrix
  }
}
```

which is extended by the Vector class that has some vector-specific methods (like e.g. calculating the length of the vector).

Now, let's say I have a vector object named, and I want to scale it by some factor. Then I would call `vector.scale(1234);` which results in a matrix object.

However, I would expect the result to be a vector object. I could of course override the scale method in the Vector class and cast the superclass's result to an object of the Vector class, but this doesn't seem like the proper way to do this.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to implement this so that I can extend the Matrix class and have objects of the subclasses return their own types of objects when they call the scale method?

Comment: You could have a method called something like `createNewInstance` which would return a new `Matrix` object in the `Matrix` class, but would be overridden in the `Vector` class to return a `Vector` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Vector extends Matrix`, you can:

```
public class Matrix {
    public Matrix scale(int scaleFactor) {
        ... return Matrix ...
    }
}

public class Vector extends Matrix {
    ...

    @Override
    public Vector scale(int scaleFactor) { // <-- return sub type here!
        ... return Vector ...
    }
}
```

The rule that overridden methods must have the same type has been weakened in Java 5: You can now use subtypes as well to make overridden methods "more specific."

The advantage of this approach over generics is that it's clean, no (implicit) casting is required and it exactly limits the types without any generics magic.

**[EDIT]** Now `Vector` is just a special kind of `Matrix` (the 1-column/row type) which means that the code in `scale()` is the same.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
public class Vector extends Matrix {
    ...

    @Override
    public Vector scale(int scaleFactor) { // <-- return sub type here!
        return (Vector) super.scale(scaleFactor);
    }
}
```

since you can't cast `Matrix` instances into a `Vector`. The solution is to move the scale code into a helper method:

```
public class Matrix {
    protected void doScale(int scaleFactor) {
        ... original scale() code here...
    }

    public Matrix scale(int scaleFactor) {
        doScale(scaleFactor);
        return this;
    }
}

public class Vector extends Matrix {
    ...

    @Override

    public Vector scale(int scaleFactor) {
        doScale(scaleFactor);
        return this;
    }
}
```

If the class is immutable (and it probably should be), then you need to use the copy constructor, of course:

```
    public Matrix scale(int scaleFactor) {
        Matrix result = new Matrix(this);
        result.doScale(scaleFactor);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I don't really see the need for generics, so this solution looks like the best one. However, the scale method is identical for both the matrix and the vector class, so unless anyone can provide a better solution, I'll just call the super.scale method in Vector's overridden scale method and cast it to the correct type.

Comment: You can't cast a `Matrix` into a `Vector`, only the other way around. If you return a new instance (and you should), then you must create a copy constructor in both types, and then `Vector result = new Vector(this); result.doScale(scaleFactor); return result;` You need `doScale()` to avoid a recursive loop.

Comment: The answers provided certainly provide a nice solution to the problem. I think it provides the best way around this problem with a minimum of code duplication. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could make `scale` generic. Like

```
public class Matrix<T> {
  // ...
  public T scale(int scaleFactor) {
    // Some code that returns a scaled version of the matrix
  }
}
```

then your sub-classes could `extend Matrix<Vector>`. Note that it would be difficult to practically implement `scale` in `Matrix`; it might be better to make it `abstract` like

```
public abstract class Matrix<T> {
  // ...
  public abstract T scale(int scaleFactor);
}
```

Then your sub-classes *must* provide an implementation.

Comment: You should show us how you can can create an instance of `Matrix`. `new Matrix()` doesn't work, since the type argument is missing. `new Matrix<Matrix>()` doesn't work, because the type argument needs a type argument itself ...

Comment: @AaronDigulla If it's abstract it **cannot** be directly instantiated.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to make it abstract, so why introduce this limitation?

Comment: @AaronDigulla There is absolutely no implementation provided by OP, so it's hard to tell exactly what it should return especially given that OP wants to vary the return type by sub-type. Further, *let superclass return type of extended class* seems to imply that it really should be `abstract`. It is possible that I'm reading too much into that sentence.

Comment: In math, a vector is a specialization of a matrix. So OO wise, the code in the question makes sense and Java supports returning extended types in overridden methods since Java 5. See my answer.

Comment: @AaronDigulia Indeeed, the vector class is a specific case of a matrix (basically a natrix with only one column). The implmentation of the scale method would therefor be identical in both the matrix and the vector class. That is why I would very much like to avoid duplicating it in both classes, but the only way I see out of this is by overriding the method in the vector subclass, assigning it the more specific Vector return type and casting the result from the Matrix superclass' scale method to a Vector object.

Answer (score 1):

An easy thing you can do is to make the method generic:

```
public <T extends Matrix> T scale(int scaleFactor) { ... }
```

When using it, you need to provide the generic type. For example, if you want a `Vector` to be returned, you have to do:

```
Matrix something = ....
Vector result = something.<Vector>scale(...);
```

Even better option is to make the `scale` method `abstract`:

```
public <T extends Matrix> T scale(int scaleFactor);
```

Then, in all subclasses of `Matrix`, you'd be forced to implement the method with a return-type that is a sub-type of `Matrix`.

Comment: I don't like this solution. It's too complex for the problem, it introduces generics where you don't need them and `scale()` can't return a `Matrix` anymore since `T` must be a subtype now - it can't be a `Matrix` itself.

Comment: And I have another reason to not like this solution: the client code looks like having a cast: `(Vector)something.scale()`.

Comment: @Ali, it's not a cast, but pointing out the generic type. There's a difference between `()` and `<>`

Comment: @kocko I know, that's why I say it LOOKS LIKE a cast, as if you had a cast. What's the point of generics if we have to specify the concrete time each time we do a call?

Comment: Well, it seems you have an issue with generics, haha. Or possibly with the design decisions from the guys from Sun. :)

Comment: To be honest, yes, generics could have been designed in a better way, but for this example, I think the cleanest solution is to re-define the method in the subclass. What you really want is to be able to return the concrete type from a method in a concrete class without duplicating the code. To me looks like you need higher-kinded polymorphism that doesn't exist in Java.

Comment: I agree on the last one.

Comment: @kocko Can you also provide the implementation of scale? You need an unsafe cast inside the implementation, right?

Answer (score 0):

You're sort of hitting one of the limits of generic types in Java, and I don't see an easy way out without re-defining `public Matrix scale(int scaleFactor)` in the subclass and then re-defining the return type: `public Vector scale(int scaleFactor)`.