# Superclass methods returning superclass object

Tags: java, superclass, return-type

I'm using the JDOM library in a solution.
I have created the following class because I want to have added capabilities (mostly `get` methods to parse specific types of data from XML elements).

```
public class MyElement extends Element {
    // methods such as...
    public Boolean getBoolean(){

    }
}
```

Of course, the elements with data are not the root element, so what I want do is this:

```
// MyElement variable "data" has been assigned before
Boolean isTest = data.getChild("isTest").getBoolean();
```

The problem is that `getChild` returns an `Element` object (as implemented by the superclass), which in turn does not know the subclass method.

From what I've read in other questions, downcasting wouldn't work?
I have thought of overriding the `getChild` method but there a downcast would be needed too, right?

Is it possible to use or override the superclass methods so that returned `Element` objects can be seen as `MyElement` objects?

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777174/java-let-superclass-return-type-of-extended-class) but that assumes you can alter the superclass's methods too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably make a static class to hold "extension methods" for Element. This is similar to Integer.parseInt(String s);

```
Boolean isTest = MyElement.getBoolean(data.getChild("isTest"));
```

An implementation would be

```
public static class MyElement {
    public static boolean getBoolean(Element e) {
        // Do your thing.
        return e.getValue() == "true" || e.getValue() == "1";
    }
}
```

You could check the instance of Element to see if it is MyElement and then cast it. But this cast will only succeed if the Element is actually of that instance. Meaning that you added constructed it and added it to your Document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've had this idea as well, for a "helper" class. Don't have to downcast (which didn't work anyway) and it looks pretty clean.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the @Overrides annotation to the method, and the compiler doesn't complain, your method will be called even if an Element.getBoolean() is defined.

```
public class MyElement extends Element {
   @Override
   public Boolean getBoolean() {
      ... whatever there was before, My element will return this ...
      return true;
   }
}
```

If you cannot add the @Override, then `Element` doesn't have a `getBoolean()` method, and as such when you do

```
data.getChild("isTest")
```

you will receive an `Element` that may happen to be a `MyElement`, but it may be something else.  While it is not the best approach under all circumstances, sometimes it is appropriate to *downcast*

```
Element element = data.getChild("isTest");
Boolean boolValue;
if (element instanceof MyElement) {
   boolValue= ((MyElement)element).getBoolean();
} else {
   boolValue= Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

I've deliberately answered without considering the actual `Element` type, as it is far more important to understand the rules than to understand the rules as they apply to only a specific class.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,but I'm getting a ClassCastException when downcasting. Went with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override `getChild` method, but you can not change return type (signature of the overriden method can not be changed), that is, you can return only type `Element` or it's subclass, which is also of `Element` type, since it extends `Element` class. Since returned subclass is hidden by super type interface, you would need to down cast returned `Element` type to your subclass.

```
Boolean isTest = ((MyElement) data.getChild("isTest")).getBoolean();
```

You can write simple method that will automatically downcast `Element` into your subclass to shortener code.

```
public static MyElement myElement(Element e) {
    return (MyElement) e;
}

// ...
    Boolean isTest = myElement(data.getChild("isTest")).getBoolean();
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,but I'm getting a ClassCastException when downcasting. Went with another solution.